# Physical placement of specific sensors in Google Nexus 7 (2012)

Tags: nexus-7, hardware, sensors

I am working on a project that requires me to know where specific sensors are physically located inside the device. I can estimate the location of NFC and light sensor (of course) but what about other sensors like magnetometer, g-sensor? If any of you know about the placement of specific sensors (doesn't have to be very precise) that would help me.

Comment: iFixIt usually does a teardown of every gadget with even a modicum of popularity. Did you check there?

Comment: iFixit's teardown can be found here: http://www.ifixit.com/Device/Nexus_7

Comment: Yes I have seen the video from iFixIt but it doesn't reveal anything but NFC sensor.

Comment: If you look at their teardown, step 5 has an image which shows where the NFC chip is, and step 16 has an image showing where the gyro and accelerometer are

Comment: NFC Antenna? (Source: ifixit) http://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/UViY1ZeTrC1JPYso.huge I think it might be that thing that says "NFC ANT" in the big orange box ^_~

Comment: Thank you for you comments. Now I am only missing magnetometer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a labeled photo of the NFC antenna behind the cover. It runs the perimeter of the black cover on the phone's back.

[image]

Comment: That appears to be for the Nexus 5 not the Nexus 7...